# ViewPager loads 2 fragments at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have 2 fragments and view pager. When I click on a button to load the first fragment the second fragment also gets loaded on the same screen.

The adapter I am using:

Adapter.java:

```
public class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    
    public Adapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }



    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        if(position==0){
            return new SettingsFragment();
        }
        if (position==1){
            return new BlankFragment();
        }
        return  null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return 2;
    }


}
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: User ViewPager 2 this is the default feature of Older ViewPager in ViewPager two you can setCurrentItem as 0 and all set

Comment: Should i set the settings fragment as 0 or the main activity fragment? @Abhishek

Comment: Why does it matter that the second Fragment is loaded along with the first? I expect that it matters because there is some data that is displayed in the second Fragment that is time sensitive and you only want loaded when the user navigates to the second fragment?

Comment: I am saying that both the fragments are loaded on the same screen. Like both the fragments are visible at the same time.

Comment: If you are saying that your viewpager is showing the second fragment on screen and not the fact that the Fragment object exists and is at a certain lifecycle state, then it is possible to configure the viewpager to show "previews" of adjacent Fragments, the "preview" could be large enough to show a lot of the fragment BUT this is not configured in the Adapter code, you have not shown us how you created and configured the Viewpager widget.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try the following:

```
private void finishActivity() {
    if(getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

Call the above method before launching the fragments.

```
finishActivity();
return new BlankFragment();
```

Comment: I tried typing getActivity but i don't see it. @PBKN

Comment: pls try, this.getActivity() or super().getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager is created to load minimum 3 pages ( 1 that user iteract with, 1 from the left, 1 from the right ), you dont need this behaviour why do use it? You can simply replace fragment in your container with animation.